# Solving $\small\begin{cases}\frac{39}{x}-\frac{11}{y}-5x+10y=0\\\frac{7}{x-2y}+x-2y+8=0\end{cases}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

$$\begin{cases}\dfrac{39}{x}-\dfrac{11}{y}-5x+10y=0\\\dfrac{7}{x-2y}+x-2y+8=0\end{cases}$$
We have $x \ne 0;2y$ and $y\ne0$. Multiplying the first and the second equation by $xy$ and $x-2y$ respectively, gives: $$\begin{cases}39y-11x-5x^2y+10xy^2=0\\7+x^2-4xy+4y^2+8x-16y=0\end{cases}$$ 
What can I do here?

Comment: Set $u=x-2y$ in the second equation and solve for $u$, as a start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $u=x-2y$ in the second equation and solve
$$\frac7u+u+8=0.$$  You'll get $u=-1$ or $u=-7$.  For $u=-1$ the first equation becomes 
$$\frac{39}{2y-1}-\frac{11}{y}-5\cdot(-1)=0$$
and for $u=-7$ we get
$$\frac{39}{2y-7}-\frac{11}{y}-5\cdot(-7)=0.$$
These are quadratics in $y$.  Only the latter has two real solutions.

Comment: How did you get $\dfrac{39}{x}=\dfrac{39}{2y-1}$?

Comment: From $u=x-2y$ and $u=-1$ we get $-1=x-2y$ and from here $x=2y-1$.

Comment: And here we must have $y\ne\dfrac{1}{2}$, right? Should I add this restriction after the equation or $x\ne0$ is enough?

Comment: Obviously.  But neither $y=0$ nor $y=1/2$ are solutions.